# Find UUID used for BT socket

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I am connecting a number of devices to a server device via BT.
I have a number of UUIDs so as to be able to connect.

However, sometimes a device will disconnect and I need to make the server discoverable and use the same UUID that the device originally used. That way I can be sure that that UUID is available.

Is there any way of knowing what UUID was used to connect to a device?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem, but i'm afraid the Android SDK does not expose a method to get the inner UUID associated with a BluetoothSocket, altough if you see in the Android source code, the BluetoothSocket knows the associated UUID.

You can create several BluetoothServerSockets listenning to different UUIDs. What you want is just a matter of not loosing the association between the BluetoothSockets created by an accept() call on a given BluetoothServerSocket. Because when you created the ServerSocket you knew the UUID.

```
public class IncommingConnectionsForAGivenUUID extends Thread
{
   private BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;
   private UUID serviceUUID;
   private boolean isRunning;

   public IncommingConnectionsForAGivenUUID(BluetoothAdapter btAdapter, UUID serviceUUID) throws IOException
   {
      this.serverSocket = btAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("localBtName", serviceUUID);
      this.serviceUUID = serviceUUID;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      this.isRunning = true;

      while(this.isRunning)
      {
         BluetoothSocket socket = this.serverSocket.accept();

         // do something with the socket...

         // this socket will have the UUID passed in 
         // the constructor. So in this point you can associate
         // this socket with the serviceUUID variable without
         // having to call a method from the BluetoothSocket
      }
   }
}
```

Ok, this isn't the only solution but it's a possible solution if you want to associate the UUID with the BluetoothSockets accepted for a given ServerSocket.

Just call this thread every time you have another UUID you wish to receive connections with.

Hope it helped ^^'